# Populate combobox options using javascript from api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, combobox

I'm looking to populate the elements of a combobox using an api call using this url
`https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLA1744`.
Basically, this api returns a list of brands that should be my options in the combobox.
This is my html

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMarca" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Marca
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMarca"></ul>
</div>
```

And my function is

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">    
  (function() {
    var dropdownMarca = document.getElementById("dropdownMarca");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var mlAPI = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLA1744";
    $.getJSON(mlAPI)
      .done(function( data ) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
            option.text = item.value);
            dropdownMarca.add(option);
          };
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

I can't manage to make it work and as you can see I'm pretty rookie. 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of issues in your code.

1. You are missing bootstrap js reference
2. Second there was no id available on your ul on which you want to add options. I have added id attribute.
3. Your callback function was not parsing data returned correctly.
4. You are attaching `option` element to your `ul`. You need to append `li` instead of `option`

I have made required adjustments in your code and now dropdown is being populated with data properly.

```js
var mlAPI = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLA1744";
    $.getJSON(mlAPI)
      .done(function(data){
           var dropdownMarca = $("#dropdownMarcaOptions");
           $.each(data.children_categories, function(index, item){                 dropdownMarca.append('<li>' + item.name + '</li>');  
           });
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMarca" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Marca
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="dropdownMarcaOptions"  class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMarca"></ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zeshan but the issue remains :( this should be simple but I just can find the error

Comment: Im using bootstrap might be related to that?

Comment: I have updated my answer and now it's working fine. Please don't forget to mark this as accepted answer if this solves your problem.